# Accessing element by variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and want to access its data. However, I need to use a variable instead of the name to access the data.

For example;

**My data:**

```
$scope.myData = {

    "user": [
        {   child[{......}],
            ..........

        }
    ],"user2": [
        {   
            child[{......}],
             .........
        }
    ],...........
```

The following works

```
 console.log("lenght:"+$scope.myData.user[0].child.length);
```

but I want to use a variable instead of `user[0]`, because it is dynamic, it changes every time.

Similar to

```
  var m=user;
  console.log("lenght:"+$scope.myData.m[0].child.length);
```

Comment: What you have is an object, not JSON. JSON is a **data format**, like XML or CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
   var m = 'user';
    console.log("lenght:"+ $scope.myData[m][0].child.length );
```